# How to close a window/popup which is not opened by the script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, smartgwt

My scenario is something like this. Technology used for UI side is SmartGwt.
In my application, `Onclick` of a button, opens a popup window, then pop up window is loaded with html contents from cross-domain url. 
I do not have popup window reference inside the html code present in pop window.

I have got close button inside the html of popup window. `Onclick` of a close button, window should get closed.

Currently its not happening. I tried with `window.close()` methods and also with window.postmessage implementation. Nothing got worked.

How do I close the popup window when window is not opened by the script?

Any ideas?

Comment: have you tried to bind `window.open('','_self').close();` to on your close button `onclick`?

Comment: @ebilgin Thats correct

Comment: @sander I tried with that.. Here I am opening pop up window through my application. and contents in pop up window are from other domain, which I have got no control. When I tried to access pop window using window. parent, I am getting this exception "Blocked a frame with origin..........."

Answer (score 0):

use this code in parent page.

```
 /*For closing the popups from inside close button*/
    closeDialog = function () {
        $("#dialog").dialog("close");
    }
```

use this code in child page.

```
   jQuery(function () {

        jQuery("#btnClose").click(function () {
            parent.closePopup();
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really familiar with SmartGwt, and as soon as you provide no code or html examples, my suggestions would be more general.

So your code should look like either:

```
    ...
    var popUp=window.open(/*arguments*/); // open the window
    ...
    popUp.close(); // close the window
```

Or you could just wrap an `iframe` with some `div` to create pseudo-popup-window (and "open"/"close" it by manipulating `iframe`'s src and wrapping `div`'s visibility) instead of opening/closing actual windows.